# Anchorusd trustworthy?

Tags: stellar-core, xlm, security, lumens

I recently decided to cash in my free lumens from last year on keybase

So I looked into it and transferred my lumens to an anchorusd account using the anchorusd android app

Keep in mind I have never transferred any cryptocurrency into USD before

But the app wants me to give it my social security number and obviously a routing/member number to send the money to my bank

Should I trust it? The social security part is what worries me most

Answer (score 0):

They are using prime trust - a regulated trust company in Nevada so they should be ok.

Other options are:

1. Wait for USDC
2. Use coinbase or another exchange and pay their fees
3. Check out other tokens

Answer (score 0):

Trust is a strong word. I was working to develop trust with AnchorUSD,(now is called tryanchor.com) however, my trust was destroyed. I wrote about it [here][1]. I'd suggest cashing out or transferring your Stellar elsewhere.
Lobstr, Nexo, Bittrex or Crypto.com are ones I have used with no problems.
[1]: https://www.publish0x.com/money-matters/updated-crypto-fans-beware-of-anchorusd-xryvnwo